# I want to calculate Saturday's and Sunday's in a date range

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want to calculate Saturday's and Sunday's in a date range? How can i ?

Comment: Are you familiar with JODA?  http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Then make yourself familiar with [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) - you'll receive joda based solutions soon (I bet)

Comment: Do yourself a favour and learn JODA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterate in days and so :

```
Calendar date ;//initiate with your date
int day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // 1=Sunday , 2=Monday , ...
```

check the day:

```
if(day == 1 || day == 7)
{
    //add to your list this **date** (for example List<Calender>
}
```

and so on.

Comment: what if i need to know days in 2 years ?

Comment: iterate each day of 2 year and check with if that added in edit

Comment: I would use `Calendar.SATURDAY` and `Calendar.SUNDAY` instead of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Find 1st Saturday&Sunday in the range, then **Calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7)** to get Saturdays&Sundays until end of range. It's faster than checking each day in the range.

Comment: @Pureth: actually you can add days to a date using JODA

Comment: If you'd replace your +7 statement with the `Calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7)` method invocation you probably have in mind, the downvotes may vanish.

Comment: @seanizer: Thanks! You said what I mean:)